# Inertia group definition

Tags: representation-theory

I don't understand the definition of inertia group: "$T_G(\theta)=\{x\in G:\, ^x\theta=\theta\}$", where $\theta$ is an irreducible character of a normal subgroup of $G$ (call it $H$) and $^x\theta$ is the conjugate character. I say that $^x h=xhx^{-1}$ and $^x\theta(h)=\theta(xhx^{-1})$). But I know that a character is constant over a conjugacy class so that $^x\theta(h)=\theta(xhx^{-1})$ is equal to $\theta(h)$ and the condition of the inertia group seems obvious. What's wrong in my thinking? Thank you!

Comment: Can you say where you found this definition?  Are you sure $\theta$ is supposed to be a character of $G$ rather than of a normal subgroup of $G$?

Comment: You're right! $\theta$ is a irreducible character of a normal subgroup $H$, I edited the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character $\theta$ is constant on conjugacy classes of $H$.  But if $x\not\in H$, then $xhx^{-1}$ may not be conjugate to $h$ in $H$ (you only know they are conjugate in $G$).  So your argument shows only that $T_G(\theta)$ contains $H$, not that it contains all of $G$.